# Problem with INNER JOIN in a CREATE VIEW FUNCTION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem creating a view. When I use an `INNER JOIN`, everything works fine, but when I try create a `VIEW`, I get this error:

> Column 'testukas.numeris' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

My query is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('testukas') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW testukas
GO

CREATE VIEW testukas
AS
    SELECT 
        a.numeris,
        tipoID,
        operatoriausID,
        planoPavadinimas,
        kaina,
        internetoPlanoID
    FROM 
        Planas AS p
    INNER JOIN 
        Abonentas AS a ON p.planoID = a.planoID
GO

SELECT 
    numeris, MAX(kaina)
FROM testukas
```

I need inputs to a solution to that.

Comment: the problem may not be with your view definition, but with the query using MAX without a group by.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear.  You need a `GROUP BY` clause because the `MAX()` makes this an aggregation query:

```
select numeris, max(kaina)
from testukas 
group by numeris;
```